# OS Signal handling loop - blocking or non-blocking read?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, signals

My application has a thread for handling OS signals, so to not block the `programLoop()`. This thread, processOSSignals, basically keeps on reading the file descriptor for signals SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGQUIT. On their reception, `loopOver` being initially true, is set to false.

```cpp
int mSigDesc = -1;

void init()
{
// creates file descriptor for reading SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGQUIT
// blocks signals with sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, nullptr)
    ...
    mSigDesc = signalfd(mSigDesc, &mask, SFD_NONBLOCK); // OR 3rd param = 0?
}

void processOSSignals()
{
    while (loopOver)
    {
        struct signalfd_siginfo fdsi;

        auto readedBytes = read(mSigDesc, &fdsi, sizeof(fdsi));
        ...
    }
}

int main()
{
    init();
    std::thread ossThread(processOSSignals);
    programLoop();
    ossThread.join();
}
```

My question is - should `mSigDesc` be set to blocking or non-blocking (asynchronous) mode?

In non-blocking mode, this thread is always busy, but inefficiently reading and returning `EAGAIN` over and over again.

In blocking mode, it waits until one of the signals is received, but if it is never sent, the ossThread will never join.

How should it be handled? Use sleep() in the non-blocking mode, to attempt reading only occasionally? Or maybe use select() in the blocking mode, to monitor `mSigDesc` and read only when sth. is available there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same advise as bk2204 outlined: Just use `poll`. If you want to have a separate thread, a simple way to signal that thread is to add the read side of a pipe (or socket) to the set of polled file descriptors. The main thread then closes the write side when it wants the thread to stop. `poll` will then return and signal that reading from the pipe is possible (since it will signal EOF).

Here is the outline of an implementation:

We start by defining an RAII class for file descriptors.

```cpp
#include <unistd.h>
// using pipe, close

#include <utility>
// using std::swap, std::exchange


struct FileHandle
{
    int fd;
    constexpr FileHandle(int fd=-1) noexcept
    : fd(fd)
    {}
    FileHandle(FileHandle&& o) noexcept
    : fd(std::exchange(o.fd, -1))
    {}
    ~FileHandle()
    {
        if(fd >= 0)
            ::close(fd);
    }
    void swap(FileHandle& o) noexcept
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(fd, o.fd);
    }
    FileHandle& operator=(FileHandle&& o) noexcept
    {
        FileHandle tmp = std::move(o);
        swap(tmp);
        return *this;
    }
    operator bool() const noexcept
    { return fd >= 0; }

    void reset(int fd=-1) noexcept
    { *this = FileHandle(fd); }

    void close() noexcept
    { reset(); }
};
```

Then we use that to construct our pipe or socket pair.

```cpp
#include <cerrno>
#include <system_error>


struct Pipe
{
    FileHandle receive, send;
    Pipe()
    {
        int fds[2];
        if(pipe(fds))
            throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category(), "pipe");
        receive.reset(fds[0]);
        send.reset(fds[1]);
    }
};
```

The thread then uses `poll` on the receive end and its signalfd.

```cpp
#include <poll.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/signalfd.h>
#include <cassert>


void processOSSignals(const FileHandle& stop)
{
    sigset_t mask;
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    FileHandle sighandle{ signalfd(-1, &mask, 0) };
    if(! sighandle)
        throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category(), "signalfd");
    struct pollfd fds[2];
    fds[0].fd = sighandle.fd;
    fds[1].fd = stop.fd;
    fds[0].events = fds[1].events = POLLIN;
    while(true) {
        if(poll(fds, 2, -1) < 0)
            throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category(), "poll");
        if(fds[1].revents & POLLIN) // stop signalled
            break;
        struct signalfd_siginfo fdsi;
        // will not block
        assert(fds[0].revents != 0);
        auto readedBytes = read(sighandle.fd, &fdsi, sizeof(fdsi));
    }
}
```

All that remains to be done is create our various RAII classes in such an order that the write side of the pipe is closed before the thread is joined.

```cpp
#include <thread>


int main()
{
    std::thread ossThread;
    Pipe stop; // declare after thread so it is destroyed first
    ossThread = std::thread(processOSSignals, std::move(stop.receive));
    programLoop();
    stop.send.close(); // also handled by destructor
    ossThread.join();
}
```

Other things to note:

1. Consider switching to `std::jthread` so that it joins automatically even if the program loop throws an exception
2. Depending on what your background thread does, you can also simply abandon it on program end by calling `std::thread::detach`
3. If the thread may stay busy (not calling `poll`) for long loops, you can pair the pipe up with an `std::atomic<bool>` or `jthread`'s `std::stop_token` to signal the stop event. That way the thread can check the flag in between loop iterations. Incidentally, your use of a plain global `int` was invalid as you read and write from different threads at the same time
4. You could also use the signalfd and send a specific signal to the thread for it to quit

Comment: Thanks for detailed solution, though it seems to be a little overcomplicated. My application needs just a receiving FD, and I could deal without Pipes and FileHandles. Question though - I suppose it makes sense to introduce some timeout on `poll`, since with -1 I run into the same problem as with blocking `read`, but this time due to `poll` itself, not `read`. BTW, my global int was just for simpler presentation of the problem.

Comment: @PiotrG Timeout isn't necessary. Just signal the poll. As I've written, in your particular case you could simply send a signal to that thread since it is waiting for signals anyway. Just ```pthread_kill(thread.native_handle(), SIGUSR1)```. OTOH most of the complexity in my program is just the RAII class for file handles and it would be good practice to have one of those anyway when you deal with raw file descriptors.

Answer (score 3):

Whether you use blocking or non-blocking I/O depends on how you want to handle your I/O.

Typically, if you have a single thread which is dedicated to reading from the signal file descriptor and you simply want it to wait until it gets a signal, then you should use blocking I/O.

However, in many contexts, spawning a single thread for each I/O operation is inefficient.  A thread requires a stack, which may consume a couple megabytes, and it's often more efficient to process many file descriptors (which may be of many different types) by putting them all in non-blocking mode and waiting until one of them is ready.

Typically, this is done portably using `poll(2)`.  `select(2)` is possible, but on many systems, it is limited to a certain number of file descriptors (on Linux, 1024), and many programs will exceed that number.  On Linux, the `epoll(7)` family of functions can also be used, and you may prefer that if you're already using such non-portable constructions as `signalfd(2)`.

For example, you might want to handle signal FDs as part of your main loop, in which case including that FD as one the FDs that your main loop processes using `poll(2)` or one of the other functions might be more desirable.

What you should avoid doing is spinning in a loop or sleeping with a non-blocking socket.  If you use `poll(2)`, you can specify a timeout after which the operation returns 0 if no file descriptor was ready, so you can already control a timeout without needing to resort to `sleep`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My application just needs to handle the 3 mentioned signals, so a single thread with 1 file descriptor is enough.